# How to get Network Interface Card names in Python?

Tags: python, networking

Is there anyway to get the names of the NIC cards in the machine etc. eth0, lo? If so how do you do it?

I have researched but so far I have only found code to get IP addresses and MAC addresses only such as

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Advice on the code would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in the standard library to query these names.

If I needed these names on a Linux system I would parse the output of `ifconfig` or the contents of `/proc/net/dev`. Look at this [blog entry](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2010/09/python-linux-parse-network-stats-from.html) for a similar problem.

Comment: What about for windows? Is there a way like this too?

Comment: Windows is not my strong side. Perhaps some of the information provided by `ipconfig /all` is suitable?

Comment: There's one in Python >= 3.3. Link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191277/650885

Answer (score 53):

A great Python library I have used to do this is [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It can be used on Linux, Windows, and OSX among other platforms and is supported from Python 2.6 to 3.6.

Psutil provides the [net_if_addrs()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_addrs) function which returns a dictionary where keys are the NIC names and value is a list of named tuples for each address assigned to the NIC which include the address family, NIC address, netmask, broadcast address, and destination address.

A simple example using `net_if_addrs()` which will print a Python list of the NIC names:

```
import psutil

addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
print(addrs.keys())
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Works on Win/Linux/Mac and is a well documented library that can be used to many other OS introspection.

Answer (score 45):

On Linux, you can just list the links in */sys/class/net/* by

```
os.listdir('/sys/class/net/')
```

Not sure if this works on all distributions.

Answer (score 27):

`socket` module in Python >= 3.3:

```
import socket

# Return a list of network interface information
socket.if_nameindex()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.if_nameindex

Comment: I would add a coment here that the Windows support was added in 3.8, not 3.3. 3.3 only supports Linux.

Answer (score 25):

Since this answer pops up in Google when I search for this information, I thought I should add my technique for getting the available interfaces (as well as IP addresses). The very nice module [netifaces](http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/) takes care of that, in a portable manner.

Comment: Nice - and it's even in the standard library. The direct answer to the actual question is then: `import netifaces; if_list = netifaces.interfaces()`

Comment: @bitinerant That's not in the standard library. It has to be installed with `pip` before it's available.

Comment: @winsome - my bad, sorry. The Python 3 package is installed by default on Ubuntu, at least 18.04 Desktop (`ubuntu-minimal` depends on `nplan` which depends on `netplan.io` which depends on `python3-netifaces`).

Comment: On Windows this library returns GUID as a network name

Answer (score 8):

Using python's `ctypes` you can make a call to the C library function `getifaddrs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ctypes import *

class Sockaddr(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('sa_family', c_ushort), ('sa_data', c_char * 14)]

class Ifa_Ifu(Union):
    _fields_ = [('ifu_broadaddr', POINTER(Sockaddr)),
                ('ifu_dstaddr', POINTER(Sockaddr))]

class Ifaddrs(Structure):
    pass

Ifaddrs._fields_ = [('ifa_next', POINTER(Ifaddrs)), ('ifa_name', c_char_p),
                    ('ifa_flags', c_uint), ('ifa_addr', POINTER(Sockaddr)),
                    ('ifa_netmask', POINTER(Sockaddr)), ('ifa_ifu', Ifa_Ifu),
                    ('ifa_data', c_void_p)]


def get_interfaces():
    libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
    libc.getifaddrs.restype = c_int
    ifaddr_p = pointer(Ifaddrs())
    ret = libc.getifaddrs(pointer((ifaddr_p)))
    interfaces = set()
    head = ifaddr_p
    while ifaddr_p:
        interfaces.add(ifaddr_p.contents.ifa_name)
        ifaddr_p = ifaddr_p.contents.ifa_next
    libc.freeifaddrs(head) 
    return interfaces

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_interfaces())
```

Do note though this method is not portable.

Answer (score 7):

To add to what @Kristian Evensen's mentions, here is what I used for a problem i was having. 
If you are looking to just get a list of the interfaces, use:

```
interface_list = netifaces.interfaces()
```

If you are wanting a specific interface, but don't know what the number at the end is (ie: eth0), use:

```
interface_list = netifaces.interfaces()
interface = filter(lambda x: 'eth' in x,interface_list)
```

Comment: @jonas I was using eth for the example. They could use lo in place of eth. I believe the answer I gave was sufficient for what the OP was asking. Not sure it was worth a downvote.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all: `get the names of the NIC cards in the machine`. You don't know the interface names or prefix at all. You should code as flexible as possible.

Comment: @jonas the first line gets those names.

Answer (score 5):

Like David Breuer say, you can just list the directory "/ sys / class / net" on Linux. (It works on Fedora at least). If you need detailled information about some interface you can navigate on the intefaces's directories for more.

```
def getAllInterfaces():
    return os.listdir('/sys/class/net/')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package get-nic which gives NIC status, up\down, ip addr, mac addr etc

```
pip install get-nic

from get_nic import getnic

getnic.interfaces()

Output: ["eth0", "wlo1"]

interfaces = getnic.interfaces()
getnic.ipaddr(interfaces)

Output: 
{'lo': {'state': 'UNKNOWN', 'inet4': '127.0.0.1/8', 'inet6': '::1/128'}, 'enp3s0': {'state': 'DOWN', 'HWaddr': 'a4:5d:36:c2:34:3e'}, 'wlo1': {'state': 'UP', 'HWaddr': '48:d2:24:7f:63:10', 'inet4': '10.16.1.34/24', 'inet6': 'fe80::ab4a:95f7:26bd:82dd/64'}}
```

Refer GitHub page for more information: https://github.com/tech-novic/get-nic-details

Comment: Currently supports Linux OS only.