# How to get meaningful network interface names instead of GUIDs with netifaces under Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use the `netifaces` module.

```
import netifaces
print netifaces.interfaces()
```

but this shows the result below:

```
 ['{CDC97813-CC28-4260-BA1E-F0CE3081DEC7}',
 '{846EE342-7039-11DE-9D20-806E6F6E6963}',
 '{A51BA5F0-738B-4405-975F-44E67383513F}',
 '{A646FA85-2EC6-4E57-996E-96E1B1C5CD59}',
'{B5DC7787-26DC-4540-8424-A1D5598DC175}']
```

I want to get a "friendly" interface name like "Local Area Connection" in Windows.

How can I get that?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781109/1145526 . See post about `psutil`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like `netifaces` leaves it up to us to pull the information out of the Windows Registry. The following functions work for me under Python 3.4 on Windows 8.1.

To get the connection name ...

```python
import netifaces as ni
import winreg as wr
from pprint import pprint

def get_connection_name_from_guid(iface_guids):
    iface_names = ['(unknown)' for i in range(len(iface_guids))]
    reg = wr.ConnectRegistry(None, wr.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    reg_key = wr.OpenKey(reg, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}')
    for i in range(len(iface_guids)):
        try:
            reg_subkey = wr.OpenKey(reg_key, iface_guids[i] + r'\Connection')
            iface_names[i] = wr.QueryValueEx(reg_subkey, 'Name')[0]
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    return iface_names

x = ni.interfaces()
pprint(get_connection_name_from_guid(x))
```

.. which on my machine produces:

```
['Local Area Connection* 12',
 'Bluetooth Network Connection',
 'Wi-Fi',
 'Ethernet',
 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network',
 '(unknown)',
 'isatap.{4E4150B0-643B-42EA-AEEA-A14FBD6B1844}',
 'isatap.{BB05D283-4CBF-4514-B76C-7B7EBB2FC85B}']
```

To get the driver name ...

```python
import netifaces as ni
import winreg as wr
from pprint import pprint

def get_driver_name_from_guid(iface_guids):
    iface_names = ['(unknown)' for i in range(len(iface_guids))]
    reg = wr.ConnectRegistry(None, wr.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    reg_key = wr.OpenKey(reg, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}')
    for i in range(wr.QueryInfoKey(reg_key)[0]):
        subkey_name = wr.EnumKey(reg_key, i)
        try:
            reg_subkey = wr.OpenKey(reg_key, subkey_name)
            guid = wr.QueryValueEx(reg_subkey, 'NetCfgInstanceId')[0]
            try:
                idx = iface_guids.index(guid)
                iface_names[idx] = wr.QueryValueEx(reg_subkey, 'DriverDesc')[0]
            except ValueError:
                pass
        except PermissionError:
            pass
    return iface_names

x = ni.interfaces()
pprint(get_driver_name_from_guid(x))
```

... which gives me:

```
['Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter',
 'Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)',
 'Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card',
 'Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller',
 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter',
 '(unknown)',
 'Microsoft ISATAP Adapter',
 'Microsoft ISATAP Adapter']
```

Comment: works with Windows 10 and Python 3.10, thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what the reg_key line is? Where does that path go?

Answer (score 10):

The Scapy module has a built in `get_windows_if_list()` that works well. (I shortened the output a bit)

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> get_windows_if_list()
[
    {'name': 'Realtek USB GbE Family Controller', 'win_index': '17', 'description': 'Ethernet', 'guid': '<guid>', 'mac': '<mac>', 'netid': 'Ethernet'},  
    {'name': 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260', 'win_index': '5', 'description': 'Wi-Fi', 'guid': '<guid>', 'mac': '<mac>', 'netid': 'Wi-Fi'}
]
```

Comment: This even works on Windows XP, which is quite unusual

Comment: This is super helpful.

Comment: N.B, almost 3 years later, this requires npcap installed, which can be surprising if you had it installed without knowing and you tried this code elsewhere

Comment: I had to use `from scapy.arch.windows import *` for `get_windows_if_list()` in scapy 2.4.5

Answer (score 1):

We can also use Windows WMI:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
qry = "select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetEnabled=True and NetConnectionStatus=2"

lst = [o.Name for o in c.query(qry)]
print(lst)
```

yields on my machine:

```
['Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller', 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1', 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8', 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter']
```

[MSDN: Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/interfaces.py#L95-L188)

the documentation of Scapy (scapy.interfaces.NetworkInterface)
NetworkInterface class have multiple data variables

```
class NetworkInterface(object):
def __init__(self,
             provider,  # type: InterfaceProvider
             data=None,  # type: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]
             ):
    # type: (...) -> None
    self.provider = provider
    self.name = ""
    self.description = ""
    self.network_name = ""
    self.index = -1
    self.ip = None  # type: Optional[str]
    self.ips = defaultdict(list)  # type: DefaultDict[int, List[str]]
    self.mac = None  # type: Optional[str]
    self.dummy = False
    if data is not None:
        self.update(data)
```

here's how you can get name

```
from scapy.all import *
l=get_if_list()
dict=IFACES.data
for item in l:
    print(dic[item].name)
```

here's how you can get Driver name

```
from scapy.all import *
l=get_if_list()
dict=IFACES.data
for item in l:
    print(dic[item].description)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extending on MaxU answer**

More accurate/refined way

```
Select Index from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True or (ServiceName<>'' 
                                                    AND ServiceName<>'AsyncMac' 
                                                    AND ServiceName<>'VMnetx' AND ServiceName<>'VMnetadapter' AND ServiceName<>'Rasl2tp' AND ServiceName<>'msloop' AND ServiceName<>'PptpMiniport' 
                                                    AND ServiceName<>'Raspti' AND ServiceName<>'NDISWan' AND ServiceName<>'NdisWan4' AND ServiceName<>'RasPppoe' 
                                                    AND ServiceName<>'NdisIP' AND Description<>'PPP Adapter.') AND MACAddress is not NULL
```

and then fire a query with respect to

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter where index= <Index>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier in PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
    Select-Object Description, SettingID, MACAddress | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP Address which your Interface uses, you could simply do something like this:

```
import netifaces as ni
def get_interfaces():
    ifaces = ni.interfaces()
    for iface in ifaces:
        try:
            ip = ni.ifaddresses(iface)[ni.AF_INET][0]["addr"]
            print(f"IP: {ip} from Interface {iface}")
        except:
            pass
```