# Python netifaces giving unusual output

Tags: python, windows, ip, network-interface, python-netifaces

I've been using netifaces in the past with no problems but recently something changed. I am not sure whether it is windows 10 fault or pythons or maybe the netifaces itself. Anyways here is what happens.

According to docs the code:

```
import netifaces

netifaces.interfaces()
```

Should give me the result similar to this:

```
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']
```

While in my case what I get is:

```
['{E3EE4C5B-38D5-4E38-ABD3-912690B3333B}', '{07ED21E7-D11D-4FAE-BCAB-00748015A895}', '{9F401909-A4A5-4AB6-8617-DFA205446FC6}', '{073251CD-250D-4FAA-889A-560941A96782}', '{6613CF18-67E7-4499-8716-58EEC449E5C6}', '{C1568B39-575B-46B3-8EA7-95A7DBA33DD0}', '{F7F856C1-2EEE-4291-B42C-444C28D7C389}', '{2FD83117-396D-11E7-81F5-806E6F6E6963}']
```

At this point I don;t know what I am dealing with and what to choose next. But using at random any of the results like this:

```
netifaces.ifaddresses('{07ED21E7-D11D-4FAE-BCAB-00748015A895}')
```

Also returns some kind of 'encrypted' results:

```
{-1000: [{'addr': 'fc:f8:ae:15:6f:0e'}], 23: [{'addr': 'fe80::ec58:f02f:37d0:598b%4', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff/128', 'broadcast': 'fe80::ec58:f02f:37d0:598b%4'}]}
```

Instead of the way it is presented in docs (looks more user friendly, doesn't it?):

```
{18: [{'addr': ''}], 2: [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}], 30: [{'peer': '::1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', 'addr': '::1'}, {'peer': '', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::1%lo0'}]}
```

Can someone explain me please what is happening and how to 'decipher' these results? What I am trying to do in the end is to obtain ip addresses of all network interfaces my pc is using.

NOTE: Python 3.6, Netifaces 0.10.5, Windows 10

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781109/1145526 . See post about `psutil`

Answer (score 3):

`['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']` are names of NICs in unix systems. On windows you get [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of network interface.
To get so called "friendly name" you can look up windows registry. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29918755/344141) (on my python 2.7 I had to import `_winreg` instead of `winreg`).