# How to count the number of network interfaces available in a system using python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python script which uses shell command to retrieve the count of interfaces available. I would like to know how to count the number of interfaces using python libraries.

This is the code section which I currently use to count the number of interfaces available:
numberOfInterfaces = int(os.popen('ls -A /sys/class/net | wc -l').read())

Comment: how do you define interface here? Do you mean network interfaces?

Comment: Yes. I mean network interface @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837069/how-to-get-network-interface-card-names-in-python and https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/

Comment: Just [edit] your question to clarify what interfaces you meant. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Library https://pypi.org/project/netifaces**

```
$ pip install netifaces

// network_interfaces.py
import netifaces
print("Total Interfaces : {}".format(len(netifaces.interfaces())))
```