# Calling In Computers IP Address

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address, ipv4

I'm trying to find a way to have Python determine what my computers IP address is and could use a hand with a weird result. A couple of quick facts, I'm using Windows 10 with the Linux Subsystem (the Ubuntu terminal app) and am running python 3.7.6.

My initial attempt at this was to use socket. i.e.,

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname() # outputs a string with the hostname 
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) # outputs a string with the relevant IP address
```

So, I thought this was working great until I tried running this on a different computer and noticed that the IP address from my computer and the different computer were the same. A quick view at the Windows command prompt showed me that my IPv4 address is completely different than what was being called by socket.

I'm not sure what the issue is here and if anyone knows, I'm all ears.

My main question is this:

> How do I call in my computer's unique IPv4 address using Python?

### EDIT:

To address the questions in the comments:

What I'm trying to do, ultimately, is access a file that is located in different directories on two different computers. I'm writing a script for a data analysis project I'm working on, and using gitlab to track my progress. But, the file paths are needing to be hardcoded into the script. To avoid dealing with changing the paths every time I switch computers, I want to add a few lines to do the following:

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname() # outputs a string with the hostname 
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) # outputs a string with the relevant IP address

if ip_address == '127.0.1.1':
    print('Working on desktop1:')
    masked_data = 'file/path/of/desktop/1/mask.pkl'
elif ip_address == 'xxx.yyy.zzz.1':
    print('Working on desktop2:')
    masked_data = 'file/path/of/desktop/2/mask.pkl'
```

This is temporary until we get a server up and running, I know it's a weird workaround. ;P

The issue with this that `ip_address` is the same for both computers when using socket. What I need to do is get the unique address of the computer I'm working on and replace the IP addresses in the loop.

Comment: It would be helpful for the question to include specifics. If you were getting `127.0.0.1` or `::1` on both machines, that's different from getting `169.254.X.Y` on two machines or `10.0.0.10` on both machines (which hopefully are connected to two different networks -- but that's something that ought to be included in the question!)

Comment: It depends on the result you want, I you want to know your wan public IP; you will need to call an external service.

Comment: ...as it is, this isn't specific enough to be answerable. We don't know what the result you *want* is (whether it's a public or private address), and we don't know what the result you're *actually getting* is, and we don't know the network topology between your test systems to know if the result you're actually getting is even unexpected or incorrect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I added an update. Please let me know if this clarifies my question.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't address the questions you've been asked, like what address are you actually getting.  You also haven't answered whether you want the public or private address.  If these are two computers on the same network and you're pulling the public address then it would be totally expected that they might have the same address.

Comment: To help you answer the questions above. If you execute the command `ifconfig` from the command line, is the IP Address you desire shown after `inet` and probably on top under `eth0:`?

Comment: `127.*` is all loopback addresses. They *all* means "the same computer I'm on right now", no matter what computer that is. And frankly, that's normal, to resolve the current system's hostname to the loopback address -- it's a lot more efficient to communicate over the loopback interface than to try to talk to a device that represents a real ethernet adapter; it also means your code doesn't break if that ethernet device gets unplugged or such.

Comment: If you want to distinguish individual systems, why not do so *by hostname*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Using `socket.gethostname()` to get your own hostname, and then `socket.gethostbyname()` to resolve that to an IP tells you what IP address your operating system is suggesting to use for loopback communication. However, that doesn't tell you anything about what addresses a system elsewhere on the network might use to communicate *with you*.

#### Use specialized tools instead.

Consider as an example [the `ifaddr` Python library](https://github.com/pydron/ifaddr), which is built specifically for the purpose of enumerating local network devices and the addresses associated with each.

Similarly, one of the answers to [How to get Network Interface Card names in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837069/how-to-get-network-interface-card-names-in-python) suggests [`git_nic`](https://github.com/tech-novic/get-nic-details), which should similarly serve the purpose.

Also, the general-purpose [`psutil` Python library](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) provides a `net_if_addrs()` function for the purpose.

Yet another 3rd-party module for the purpose is [`netifaces`](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces).