# (Python 3) Get Device Name, IP Address, MAC Address and Packet sent and recieved from the devices

Tags: python, networking, ip, device

I need to get the Device Name, IP address, MAC address, and packets sent and received from that devices inside and outside the network. Something similar to this. [lanscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov1e2.png)

Any help please?

I have found many example for IP and MAC Adresses but none for device name. For example my Samsung galaxy s9 cell phone is connected to my wifi so I want to get its name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Network Interface Card names in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837069/how-to-get-network-interface-card-names-in-python)

Comment: @Aziz No, it returns IP Addresses and MAC address but not Device name. Eg my Samsung galaxy s9 cell phone is connected to my wifi so I want to get its name.

Answer (score 1):

You can get IP and Mac address using socket package . To get the Device name the device has send a DHCP Request to the router which has Host field in it which contains Device Model . So to force the device to send an DHCP Request , first you've have to disconnect them using Deauthentication attack or any other method if you prefer . So when they try to connect again then we can see the DHCP Request send by them which we can capture and see the Host field in it for Device Name .

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a solution in code, but this guy does:

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGJC5vT5YJo&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDdduy0IPDDHYnUx66Vc4ed*

It's a playlist about a python sniffer which is what you want to do,
but for the Device Name you can use

```
import socket as s

s.getfqdn("localhost") #  DESKTOP-L7B4S7M (I'm in a windows machine)

#  in localhost you put the IP
```