# What IP should i put in place of 'localhost' in this example for socket python

Tags: python, sockets, localhost

I am trying to build a client and server script to interact with each other using sockets, but I am confused on where to find the IP that I should put in place of 'localhost' in this example. Someone please help direct me on where to find the thing to put in place of it.

Server side:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
```

Client Side:

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
```

Comment: If both your client and server run on the same host, `localhost` is completely acceptable. It's simply an alias for `127.0.0.1`

Comment: If they are NOT on the same host, then `bind()` the server to `0.0.0.0` (ie, all local network adapters) or the server's actual LAN IP, and then `connect()` the client to the server's LAN IP. Use a tool like `ipconfig` on the server to see what IPs it has available. Or use a script to [query the IPs in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837069/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the insight, however I am still receiving a 'TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond' error when using the right IP? What else might be the problem here, as I am kind of lost on what to try and do next. Thank you once again