# How to generate a unique specific ID in python that's derived from the hardware info on any system (Mac, Linux or Windows)?

Tags: python, security, encryption, cryptography, cross-platform

I want to derive a master key solely from the system on which the user is working on, I don't want to store a master key so then we decided to derive a unique ID from the system the user will be working on.

For example if a user is on System A, everytime the code runs it should return the same key, but on System B it'll change (ofc).

And we will derive it everytime when the app runs, so there's no hassle of storing the key on another secured file with another key and so on.

I couldn't figure out how would I do this on Mac and simultaneously on windows and linux, as I need my program to be cross-platform.

I've seen few videos that use a library called uuid but it always fetches a different ID everytime the program runs.

Using that will change the fetched ID to the key I derived from the initial ID, and that's a probleM, also that I've only seen solutions for only windows and linux systems, what about MacOS.

An ID derived from the host system and then the children keys being derived from that master key is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Get the hardware IDs for this purpose. A network hardware ID must exist cross-platform for Internet connection. A webcam or harddrive serial numbers are another options.

Comment: Be aware that hardware IDs can be spoofed. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I think you should explain the _why_ behind what you're doing a little more to give a more correct answer.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837069/how-to-get-network-interface-card-names-in-python

Comment: @gvee Thanks for the tip! Okay so I am building a password manager but I need a master key, now I don't want to resolve in storing my key on a separate file, instead I'd grab something unique of a system and manipulate it, simple, but I couldn't find a suitable way to grab any sort of ID from a system that's cross platform

Comment: @Claudio that's interesting! Imma try that-

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pprint import pprint
print('===================')

import psutil
pprint(f'{psutil.net_if_addrs().keys()=}')

print('===================')

import socket
pprint(f'{socket.if_nameindex()=}' )

print('===================')

import netifaces           # https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/
pprint(f'{netifaces.ifaddresses(netifaces.interfaces()[-1])=}')

print('===================')

from get_nic import getnic # https://pypi.org/project/get-nic/
pprint(f'{getnic.ipaddr(getnic.interfaces())=}')

print('===================')
```

Comment: The output from this does not satisfy the intended use of my case, would there by any way to get a string output about anything but for that system, thanks for the effort btw!

Comment: Have I got you right? You want to get data from the system which are always there, unique to the system and stay the same all the time, but you don't want the data to be accessible to read them because if they were you could just also save them in a protected area of a harddrive, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: I think just extracting the mac id from the network card does it :)